# Tab Bar Controller Methods and Properties in other ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have been looking around and I can't find any clear answers. How can I access methods and properties written in the TabBarController from a ViewController attached to it?

The TabBarController has ViewControllers A and B attached to it. VCA has VA1, and VCB has VC2 each connected by a segue. How can I allow VC1 to use methods and properties found on TabBarController.

Comment: self.tabBarController

Comment: that's actually even better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case your tab bar controller can be accessed via `parentViewController` of child VCs, unless those are inside their own containers, like navigation VC, then you'll need to go up one level.

Comment: How would I go up one level? You're right, the child VCs are in a nav controller and that is in the tab bar controller. I have tried parentViewController it crashes the app

Comment: Simply, `self.parentViewController.parentViewController`. It's hard to tell of the nature of the crash, you should go into debugger and play with child VCs, check what parent/presenting properties are set.

Comment: I have a counter in the tab bar controller called tabCount.To access it from VC1, I tried using `self.parentViewController.parentViewController.tabCount` in VC1.m  but it says the property isn't found

Comment: Right, because parentViewController returns `UIViewController*`, you would need to cast to tab bar like `(UITabBarController*)self.parentViewController`. Although, this solution does not look good, you can, for example, post a NSNotification with tab count and then process it in, say, app delegate

Comment: Instead of using notifications and the app delegate, would it be better to use a singleton class? Or is this bad practice?

Comment: I don't find singletons bad, but it always depends, I guess. NSNotificationCenter is a singleton in itself